# p-value distribution for enrichment analysis

Tags: distributions, p-value, binomial-distribution

I am doing a gene ontology enrichment analysis and end up with an unexpected distribution for my p-values.

**My questions:**

- Why does this happen?
- Can I anyway use the p-values to interpret if terms are enriched?
- How can it be corrected?

I am not a statistician and appreciate simple answers.

---

HERE ARE THE ANALYSIS DETAILS:

**Goal:** 
determine which GO terms are over- or underrepresented in the candidate proteins.

**Input data:**

- set of background proteins
- set of candidate proteins

**Enrichment analysis:**

For each GO term:

1. Record the GO term's frequency among the background proteins (e.g. GO term “nucleus” is associated with 5 out of 100 background proteins and therefore has a frequency of 5%)
2. Calculate how many hits we expect among the candidate proteins (= number of candidate proteins * background frequency)
3. Count how many candidate proteins are associated with the GO term.
4. Calculate a p-value to check if the actual and the expected hits are significantly different.

The calculation assumes a binomial distribution and does a binomial test in the respective direction (i.e. if actual occurrences < expected: calculate probability for getting a value the same or lower than the actual one; if actual > expected: same or higher value).

**p-value distribution:**

The p-values look bimodal with a large peak towards 1 and a small number of GO terms having p-values < 0.05.

[image: p-value distribution]

This distribution intuitively makes sense to me: most GO terms are not enriched. Thus, the number of actual and expected hits are the same, resulting in high p-values and a peak to the right.

However, many sources state that the p-value distribution should look like this:
[image: proper p-value distribution]